# finding the net inertial force on an object on earth

Tags: inertial-frames

I  was asked to find the condition(velocity ) for which the net inertial force with respect to earth acting on a body moving at fixed latitude to be 0.

Firstly I thought the coriolis force must be made 0 by moving  it along the parallels of latitude. Then I tried to find the condition for which centrifugal force is 0. I thought if we move it with the speed equal to the speed of rotation of earth at that latitude, i. e. R w cos x....R being radius of earth,  w being angular speed of earth and x being latitude ,also moving in same direction. But do we need to consider the effect of the revolution of earth? Please help& correct if I am wrong.

Comment: I asked , if there are any inertial forces generated due to the revolution of earth? I thought of the coriolis force and the centrifugal force and tried to make their magnitude 0. But are there any other forces coming into play?